# Remove WordPress admin bar on a single page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there a way to remove the WordPress admin bar but just on a specific page?

I know that I can remove it or hide it completely by adding an action:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

I've done that but on my site I have one page that is displayed in an iframe (using colorbox) and I don't ever want the admin bar to show up in that iframe.

Is there a way to hide the admin bar but just for a specific page?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: If(get_the_ID()==#736637){
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar'); function remove_admin_bar() { if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) { show_admin_bar(false); } }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is a bit complicated, there's a filter for that. Just check for the Page ID and filter it out using the [`show_admin_bar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar) filter.

```
function riga_hide_admin_bar(){
    if( $post->ID == YOUR_POST_ID ){
        return false;
    }
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'riga_hide_admin_bar' );
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks promising.  I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove WordPress admin bar on a single page
```

Yes, you can remove admin bar from a specific page as you wish. 
Use `add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );` to hide admin bar from a specific page.

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

For more details please see below link:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/show_admin_bar

Comment: Sorry but I'm not seeing how that checks for a specific page.  Wouldn't that just remove the admin bar on every page?

Answer (score 0):

Get ID of specific page and add your filter in condition which meet the page ID

```
`If(get_the_ID()==#736637){
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
     }
   }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way is to add the code in the template of the page I don't want to show. At the top of the template file I just add:

```
<?php
show_admin_bar(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to remove the 32px margin added to the `html` element.